# ProcessBuilder not working on server but work fine on localhost

Tags: java, webserver, runtime, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute an external .exe that create a custom file an saves it on the server the i can

my code for `ProcessBuilder` work fine on localhost but when i'm deploying it on my server, the document is not created andI have no error in my java web server

I tried to play with the environment variable of the `ProcessBuilder` but no luck on that still not working

I'm out on ideas

Pleaze help me out Thats

Here is my code for processBuilder that works fine on localhost

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("pathtoExe\\executable.exe");
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.redirectOutput();
    processBuilder.redirectInput();
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    String s;
    System.out.printf("Output of running is:");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print("ligne out: ");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println(process.exitValue());
}
catch (IOException| InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Error message you get?

Comment: i get no error message and the exitvalue is 0 my code works on localhost but when i deploy on my glassfish server it does nothing

Comment: By coincidence, does that glassfish server reside on Linux?

Comment: no its on windows server 2008

Comment: Are those `redirectOutput` and `redirectInput` calls necessary there?

Comment: nope... i was tring go see if my exe was sending error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it might help someone, I found out that the user that start glassfish service did not had the rights to execute on network.

I put a user with the good rights and Voilà..

Thanks.